# Get stored procedure _return_ value using NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I need to get **return value** from a stored procedure, using NHibernate.

The procedure cannot be modified.

```
Create procedure TesteProcedure
as
    DELETE FROM TesteTable
    WHERE RefDate < GETDATE()

    RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;
Go
```

.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="T" namespace="T.teste">
  <sql-query name="procedure">
    exec [dbo].[TesteProcedure]
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: That is unfortunate you can't fix the procedure. The return value is intended to be used to indicate the status of the execution. An OUTPUT parameter is what should be used to return a value. I can't even spell hibernate so I am no help on that part of the puzzle.

Comment: This is a old system SP, which I can´t change. thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long standing method is to use ADO.NET in conjunction with NHibernate. Here is an example: http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-legacy-stored-procedures-in.html

Comment: Well, not the answer I wanted, I wish there were something with NHibernate, but I will not waste such a time to find out, furthermore this solution works fine, thx